# passing input value to a href php

Tags: php, html

I want to pass input field value to another page using `<a>` tag

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="plate" value="'. $value["plate"] . '" />
<a href="vehicle_edit.php?edit=' . $value["plate"] . '&edited=' . $value["plate"] . '">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="float:right;margin-top:5px;">Update</button>
</a>
```

note that the input field value is going to be edited and pass to another page along with the first version of `$value["plate"]`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is it you're confused about? Variables in the query string will be available in the `$_GET` array.

Comment: i want to get the edited value of <input> and make it available like this - -

Comment: you are currently mixing `html` and `php` in a way that does not work.

Comment: what i want to get is like this -> vehicle_edit.php?edit=AA456&edited=456

Comment: You would have to use JavaScript to get the value of the input and add it to a query string of you link.

Comment: @JayBlanchard could you please post some code snippet for your suggestion.

Comment: If you want an input value that changes to be posted to another URL you won't be able to do this in PHP as the PHP loads server side before the page loads. A common method to do what you are attempting to do is with "form action= post". And to have the "a href=" tag be equal to the input value you can use "input1 = document.getElementById("#input").value;
   document.getElementById("#a").innerHTML = input1;"  Getting the above code to work in a <script> will change the a href="" to be equal to what is in the input field. You can call the function when the button is clicked using "onclick"

Comment: you need to use the $_GET superglobal in the next page and capture those in there.

Answer (score -1):

You will either have to use a `<form>` tag, with a hidden field containing the original value, or use jQuery or similar to grab the value of the edited field and append it to the href

Example assuming jQuery:

```
<input id="plate" type="text" name="plate" value="<?php echo $value["plate"];?>" />
<a id="updateBtn" href="#">Update</a>
<script> 
$(function() { 
    $('#updateBtn').on('click',function(){ 
        var edited = $('#plate').val(); 
        $(this).prop('href', 'vehicle_edit.php?edit=<?php echo $value["plate"];?>&edited=' + edited);
        return true; 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: assuming using jQuery:    

`<input id="plate" type="text" class="form-control" name="plate" value="<?php echo $value["plate"];?>" />
<a id="updateBtn" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="float:right;margin-top:5px;">Update</a>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#updateBtn').on('click',function(){
  var edited = $('#plate').val();
  $(this).prop('href', 'vehicle_edit.php?edit=<?php echo $value["plate"];?>&edited=' + edited);
  return true;
 }); 
});
</script>`

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments, it is unreadable. Edit you post to include any new information.

Comment: OK done that, not too familiar with the formatting functions here.Apols